# Background color of rows in WPF datagrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, background-color

I've got a WPF datagrid bound to a list of parts and I need alternating row colors.  The parts can also be part of a group, in which case the entire group needs to be the same color.  Kind of like:

```
Part 1, group 1  -  White background
Part 2, group 2  -  Blue background
Part 3, group 3  -  White background
Part 4, group 3  -  White background
Part 5, group 4  -  Blue background
Part 6, group 4  -  Blue background
Part 7, group 5  -  White background
```

The alternation of color must be based on groups, not simply by every other row.  I have tried using grid.ItemContainerGenerator in the codebehind when the source collection is updated, but this does not work.  ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex() always returns null at this time, I suppose because the grid is still updating, I don't know.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In complex scenarios (like color denoting status, for example), I create a property on the viewmodel that returns a Color for the BackgroundBrush based on whatever rules you want.  I typically create a static instance that I return repeatedly for each group, and freeze it, to conserve resources.

HTH...

Answer (score 0):

I have used RowLoaded/RowUnloaded in the past, and using a behavior told the row what property of the rows datacontext contains the background. The problem that I have found is that binding a rows Background for some reason climbs up to the Grid's DataContext, instead of using the rows. If you are interested in this approach I can paste the code I have use. It does require that the ViewModel or ListViewModel be aware enough to set the correct colors for the rows. I have been often on the fence about colors in ViewModel, but color has become a business need and not just an ascetic effort.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was overriding the following event of the DataGrid class

```
protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(System.Windows.DependencyObject element, object item)
```

After calling the base method, you can set background color of the row based on the value of the *item* variable, which you can convert to group class and access properties such as group name for example.